# Color.White not visible when drawing GraphicsPath

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing

The following code works fine when I use any other color than Color.White:

```
Public Sub PaintVignette(ByVal b As Bitmap, ByVal uColor As Color, ByVal bounds As Rectangle)

    Dim d As Double = 0.70712

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
        Dim ellipsebounds As Rectangle = bounds
        ellipsebounds.Offset(-ellipsebounds.X, -ellipsebounds.Y)
        Dim x As Integer = ellipsebounds.Width - CInt(Math.Round(d * ellipsebounds.Width))
        Dim y As Integer = ellipsebounds.Height - CInt(Math.Round(d * ellipsebounds.Height))
        ellipsebounds.Inflate(x, y)
        Using path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
            path.AddEllipse(ellipsebounds)
            Using brush As PathGradientBrush = New PathGradientBrush(path)
                brush.WrapMode = WrapMode.Tile
                brush.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
                brush.SurroundColors = New Color() {Color.FromArgb(255, uColor.R, uColor.G, uColor.B)}
                Dim blend As Blend = New Blend()
                blend.Positions = New Single() {0F, 0.2F, 0.4F, 0.6F, 0.8F, 1.0F}
                blend.Factors = New Single() {0F, 0.5F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F}
                brush.Blend = blend
                Dim oldClip As Region = g.Clip
                g.Clip = New Region(bounds)
                g.FillRectangle(brush, ellipsebounds)
                g.Clip = oldClip
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Passing Color.Green as the color argument results in such an image:

[image]

Passing Color.White results in such an image:

[image]

As one can see, the color White isn't drawn at all.

Does anybody see what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the individual pixels (mainly those of the grid) in your screenshot you'll see that the vignette is infact drawn even when you use `Color.White`, though it is barely visible:

[image: Proof that the code works]

It is hard to notice it because you have a white background and because the vignette is rather transparent. To be able to see it more clearly you'll need to decrease the transparency (or increase the intensity, whichever terminology is correct) of the vignette.

Note that since both the vignette and the background is white, drawing it will only affect non-white pixels (i.e. the grid). If you want to make it more like a shadow you'll have to change the color to some variation of gray.